# How to set the name of a Streaming File into a SetProperties in MuleSoft?

Tags: file, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I want to set the name of a streaming file into a SetPropertie in MuleSoft , Any idea about that ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge we cannot perform it instead we can store the payload in **session variable** and we can write it with the different filename.